# ¿Como puedo conectarme a internet usando Perl

Tags: linux, perl

Estoy aprendiendo Perl y necesito crear un programa que por consola le ingresé una palabra, y con un script hecho puramente es Perl haga búsquedas por la web, o que simplemente se pueda conectar a internet y visitar alguna página web, estoy usando Linux (Ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el módulo LWP para hacer peticiones HTTP. Con el módulo LWP::Simple incluso de forma mucho más simple.